# Google Cloud Build/App engine error at Syncinc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml

I'm Attempting to deploy a *Flask* (python3) App to **Google App Engine** using **Google Cloud Build**, but am getting the following error:

> failed unmarshalling build config app.yaml: unknown field "runtime"

My app.yaml is as follows:

```
runtime: python37
resources:
  memory_gb: 2.0
```

The weird things is that I can deploy the service correctly using the CLI, but not using the activators.

I'm currently using Bitbucket and it seems that the activator is ok (webhook is activated as soon as I push a commit to the desired branch, but the mentioned message appears and the build is unsuccessful).

I followed this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/writing-web-service

Comment: Can you share your cloudbuild.yaml file?

Comment: Hi, there's no cloudbuild.yaml. I followed a google tutorial where I just added app.yaml. Is cloudbuild.yaml needed for Google Cloud Build, while app.yaml for just normal deploy?

Comment: can you please add the tutorial you followed?

Comment: @marian.vladoi Added

Comment: I understand that you were able to follow this tutorial and deployed the service. However I do not know how you set up cloud build with Bitbucket for this service [Creating and managing build triggers](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers).